# Theming mini panel using MYTHEME_preprocess_panels_pane

Tags: 7, theming, panels

I'm trying to edit the content of a mini panel using MYTHEME_preprocess_panels_pane but when I use Devel to dsm $variables, I just get data for the pane that holds the mini panel.

Is there a function to get into the mini panel?

At first I thought hook_panels_pane_content_alter might work but I'm getting nothing when I drop it into my template.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at the content on a mini panel using hook_panels_pane_content_alter.

It needs to be called in a custom module (see https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7)